# AngularJS select integer value with HTML select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I have a very simple task: select an integer value with angular using an HTML `<select>` tag.

```
<select ng-model="foo.bar">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

`foo.bar` holds an integer value. When I run the above code, the first generated option is: `<option value="? number:32 ?"></option>`. I have found out that the selected value is interpreted as a String. I want an Integer.

I have found some possible solutions, but they are either complex (like the [documentation example to implement a `convert-to-number`-function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#binding-select-to-a-non-string-value-via-ngmodel-parsing-formatting)) , or their `options` array looks different (mine is just a simple array of integers).

Comment: Select will give you a string only you have to convert that value to number like number(value)

Comment: So where can I make that conversion?

Comment: In your controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the `option` tag combined with `ng-repeat` you should use angulars [`ng-options` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) like this:

```
<select ng-model="foo.bar" ng-options="option for option in options"></select>
```

If `options` is an array of integers, `ng-model` should contain an integer as well.

Comment: Note that [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) expected expression must look like `_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_`. Change `ng-options` to `option for option in Options` and it would work.

Comment: Great answer! No need to parse the integer in the controller! :) I tried to do something similar, but I couldn't get the `ng-options`-part correct.

Answer (score 0):

Select will give you a string. You will have to convert that string into a number in your controller code.

```
foo.bar = parseInt(foo.bar);
```

You may need to use a watch to look for changes in your foo.bar variable and then parse them to integer.

Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope and search for $watch.

Comment: Why there is a need for unnecessary $watch?

Comment: Because if he wants to use foo.bar in another part of his code he will need to parse it to integer at digest time

Comment: Why parse the integer explicitly at all when you can use `ng-options` as Freddy suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Select dropdown will give you string value always, if you want it to be an integer covert it in controller

**Controller** -

```
var numValue = Number(foo.bar);
```